# EhCache 3 with Atomikos Transaction Manager

Tags: atomikos, ehcache-3

Right now, I am using EhCache 2 with Atomkios as JTA provider. I am able to configure transaction manager as below.

```html
   FactoryConfiguration config = new FactoryConfiguration();
        config.setProperties("jndi=java:comp/UserTransaction");
        config.setPropertySeparator("=");
        config.setClass("net.sf.ehcache.transaction.manager.DefaultTransactionManagerLookup");
        ehCacheConfig.transactionManagerLookup(config);
```

Now, I plan to migrate to EHCache 3, however i found that Bitronix is only supported JTA as out of box. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/xa.html

Can anyone please help to configure Atomikos with EhCache 3 ??

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, supporting the Atomikos TM in Ehcache 3 would require writing some glue code, and that simply hasn't been done yet. You could file an enhancement request, or better still: help us add that support. What is needed is documented at https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/xa.html#configuring-your-transaction-manager